# Does creating and closing database connections each time I need them have any effect?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I recently faced an

> org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY] The database file is locked (database is locked)

error on my desktop application because I think I used a single connection to read and write data across my methods. So, I changed from using a single connection to creating a new connection each time I was reading and writing to my application. For
example, in each method for reading my data, I did:

```java
try {
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    // rest of my code
    connection.close();
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Note, that it fixed my issue**.

My question is, are there any effects of doing what I just described above?

Comment: Which SQLite library are you using?

Comment: The first time you run a query against a newly opened database, sqlite has to read the `sqlite_master`/`sqlite_main` table and parse all the create statements it stores in order to build internal data structures describing the layout of the database. This can be slow. Much better to open the database once and reuse the same connection over the life of your program.

Comment: @Shawn, doing exactly what you said is what gave me that error in the first place

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin, I am using org.xerial found here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.42.0.0

Comment: Do you have other programs using the same database running at the same time? (Or a separate connection in the same program?)

Comment: @Shawn, It is one project, so it is not like many programs or anything.  I just wanted to know if there are any issues with my method (which is working, of course) and it has been clarified by a provided answer below, so I am good. Thank you for your input

Comment: So, you get busy errors when a *different* connection has the database locked. This can be as simple as forgetting to end a transaction in one blocking other attempts to use it, or a sign you're doing something like wanting to have connections be able to read from the same database another connection is in the middle of writing to (solution: wal journal mode), or trying to have multiple connections write simultaneously (in which case sqlite is the wrong database to use). You need to figure out the underlying cause to properly address it instead of covering it up with a bandaid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading and writing data also required to close resources such as `Statement` and `ResultSet`. These resources needs to be closed after each query. If you forget to close resources then you face a resource leaks which is a case of the memory leaks problem. Each time you make a query to the database it is openning a transaction and ends it after the statement is executed if the auto-commit mode is on.

> The `Connection` object should be closed at the end of the method. If you didn't close connection it will stay active and keep memory, it imposes a memory leaks (also known as resource leaks). In the java 8 and above this object implements [`AutoClosable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface and can be used with [*try-with-resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement. The same is related to `Statement` and `ResultSet` that you should close accordingly. But if you close the connection explicitly then these objects are closed also.
>
> ```
> try (Connection connection = db.getConnection();) {
>  //your code here                         
> }catch(SQLException e) {
>  db.getErrorMessages(e);
> }
> ```

Transactions lock the database resources but they can impose a deadlock problem if the same resources are used by different threads. To avoid these and many other problems, that you may encounter while using JDBC, use connection per thread pattern and close resources after their usage.

You have two options:

1. Get a new connection each time you perform a query and close it afterwards along with all resources.
2. Use a data source to get a connection. This requires to configure a connection pool to your application.

Which method you use depends on user requirements of your application.